# How can i post tha data to web page or server..? from i-phone app. and get reply also

Tags: ios4

i want to post the data in this link --www.google.co.in/dictionary?source=translation&hl=en&q=&langpair=en|hi--

it is for translation.
any body can help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/8160-tutorial-request-complete-http-post-request.html

Very good tutorials here